# pass list of objects from pyqt5 to qml returns undefined

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyqt5

I would like to pass a list of dictionaries from pyqt5 to qml where this list becomes the `model` of `ListView` element. The following code is what i have so far.

main.py

```
class MainWindow(QQuickView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.model = model.PersonModel()
        self.rootContext().setContextProperty('PersonModel', self.model)
        self.rootContext().setContextProperty('MainWindow', self)
        self.setSource(QUrl('main.qml'))

    @pyqtSlot()
    def personsList(self):
        print(self.model.persons) # this prints the list of objects perfectly fine
        return(self.model.persons)
        .
        .
        .
```

main.qml

```
ListView {
    id: listExample
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: MainWindow.personsList()
    delegate: PersonDelegate { }
    highlight: highlightComponent
    highlightMoveDuration: 0
    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log(">>>", MainWindow.personsList()) // returns undefined, but why??
    }
}
```

model.py

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractListModel, Qt, QModelIndex 

class PersonModel(QAbstractListModel):

    NAME_ROLE = Qt.UserRole + 1
    AGE_ROLE = Qt.UserRole + 2

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.persons = [
            {'name': 'jon', 'age': 20},
            {'name': 'jane', 'age': 25},
            {'name': 'pete', 'age': 25},
            {'name': 'winson', 'age': 25},
            {'name': 'ben', 'age': 25},
            {'name': 'jiahao', 'age': 25}            
        ]

        self.currentIndex = 0

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        row = index.row()
        if role == PersonModel.NAME_ROLE:
            return self.persons[row]["name"]
        if role == PersonModel.AGE_ROLE:
            return self.persons[row]["age"]

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.persons)

    def roleNames(self):
        return {
            PersonModel.NAME_ROLE: b'name',
            PersonModel.AGE_ROLE: b'age'
        }

    def updateIndex(self, int):
        self.currentIndex = int
        print("updating index from click", self.currentIndex)

    def addPerson(self, name, age):
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        self.persons.append({'name': name, 'age': age})
        self.endInsertRows()

    def insertPerson(self, row, name, age):
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), row, row)
        self.persons.insert(row, {'name': name, 'age': age})
        self.endInsertRows()

    def editPerson(self, row, name, age):
        ix = self.index(row, 0)
        self.persons[row] = {'name': name, 'age': age}
        self.dataChanged.emit(ix, ix, self.roleNames())

    def deletePerson(self, row):
        self.beginRemoveColumns(QModelIndex(), row, row)
        del self.persons[row]
        self.endRemoveRows()
```

why does the list of persons return undefined in qml?

In case anyone is wondering, i am trying to create a model class that i can instantiate with by passing any list of dictionaries and use this list as the `model` property in different `ListView` elements. In this model class i have `add`, `insert`, `edit`, `delete` that i can use consistently throughout all instances and thus avoid repetitions.

Also, i am trying to separate the model from the view such that the data flow is one way ie `qml` informs python of any user interaction and all changes in the `model` will be handled on python which qml will change accordingly whenever `model` changes.

Comment: The code that samples of the model is not enough to analyze which is the error, you could place the code of the complete model.

Comment: hi eyllanesc! i've edited and placed the full model.py in my question.

Comment: The way you interact with python with qml is unsuitable, what do you really want to do?

Comment: could you explain why it is unsuitable? im thinking of creating a generic model class that acts like a list generator and take in different lists of dictionaries that will have the same methods. each instance of this generic model will be used as the `model` property in different `ListView` in qml

Comment: Will the models you create have the same roles? Also why do you want to send a dictionary from python to QML?

Comment: roles will be different but methods like add, delete etc will likely be the same. i meant list of objects. apologies. so list of objects from python to qml that serves as the data model for qml

Comment: a list of objects is not a model. Check and test my answer.

Comment: for QML to recognize your data as a model from the python side there are 2 possibilities, the first is to pass an object to a class that inherits from QAbstractItemModel [Question-Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814961/how-to-insert-edit-qabstractlistmodel-in-python-and-qml-updates-automatically) , or the second is to pass a list of objects of a class that inherits from QObject  [Question-Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387666/passing-a-python-list-of-objects-to-qml)

Comment: yea. it worked! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt there is the `Q_INVOKABLE` macro that enables and registers the function so that it can be used from `QML`, in PyQt its equivalent is a  `pyqtSlot()` that we have to tell you what kind of data it returns through the `result` parameter.

```
@pyqtSlot(result=list)
def personsList(self):
    print(self.model.persons)
    return self.model.persons
```

An error that is observed in your QML code is that you are passing as a model to ListView a list of objects instead of the model:

```
import QtQuick 2.6

ListView {
    id: listExample
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: PersonModel
    delegate: Text{
        text: name
    }
    highlightMoveDuration: 0
    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log(">>>", MainWindow.personsList()) // returns undefined, but why??
        var l = MainWindow.personsList();
        for(var counter in l){
            console.log(l[counter]['name'] + ": " + l[counter]['age'])
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'jon', 'age': 20}, {'name': 'jane', 'age': 25}]
qml: >>> [[object Object],[object Object]]
[{'name': 'jon', 'age': 20}, {'name': 'jane', 'age': 25}]
qml: jon: 20
qml: jane: 25
```

Answer (score 1):

I am in a MeeGo phone, limited to `import QtQuick 1.0`, and have been trying to send python objects (lists, dictionaries, tuples) via a Slot to a user interface written in qml:

```
@Slot(str, result=list)
```

at the `qml` end I have been trying this:

```
var l = app.get_taxonomic_derivation(lookup_text.text)
print (l)
print (l.length)
```

and all I was getting was:

```
QVariant(PySide::PyObjectWrapper)
undefined
```

which I did not manage to convert into a list, no idea how.

I ended up using json, with `eval` at the client side.

```
@Slot(str, result=str)
def get_taxonomic_derivation(self, epithet):
    ....
    return json.dumps(result)
```